# Web services calls in a loop

Tags: web-services, rest, web, architecture

some of my colleges made some simple web service interface for us.

However, process is kind of bit long running which is fine and expected. But, the problem is, this is what they think of:

- Make a first request, get a id in response
- Using that id, create requests in a loop, until process is finished
- Make one final request, essentially just to do the cleanup.

How about make one, single web method, so that I can make one single request? If it is longer, and it is, then increase your timeout. It's alright, I can wait...

Hell no!

What could go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Long running processes over HTTP have always given me trouble.  HTTP does not like long-running requests, many network appliances put hard limits on the length of requests, and others have default timeouts that need to be tweaked.

I much prefer a series of smaller requests to check the status of long-running processes.  It's more code, but it causes far fewer problems down-stream.  I generally like this pattern to be implemented using the [HTTP 202](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) response code to indicate whether the process has completed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't ever remember having any problems with long running web methods. Well, except that I need adjust timeout of course. So this would be my first implementation of this pattern and looks very odd to me. In fact it resembles to a something like a DoS attack or just plain abuse. I'm just wondering has someone ever had this kind of implementation and what could go wrong....

Comment: Yes, it's fairly common.  It's probably worth putting a slight delay between calls if the connection is low-latency, just to avoid the amount of traffic.

Comment: Well, if it fairly common, how come that didn't run into until now. And I still don't understand how can spawning multiple, hundreds or even thousands of new requests (and new threads, new authorizations and everything) can cause less problems then one, single request?

Comment: Because the web is optimized for short-lived http request/response cycles.  I have no idea why you haven't run into it before now, perhaps you haven't had to work with a system that has long-running processes.    Here are some examples of other people that have asked similar questions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542202/how-to-work-with-long-lasting-http-requests or http://farazdagi.com/blog/2014/rest-long-running-jobs/.  Read the first couple of results from googling: long running http request

Comment: Think about this from a service provider architecture.  Generally, long-running tasks shouldn't be handled on-thread on a web server.  Web servers have a limited number of threads, and if you have thousands of users trying to do long-running operations, you will quickly exhaust thread pools (load balancing this is tricky too, as most load balancers balance on number of requests dispatched).  It is much cleaner to throw a message on a queue, and have a worker process pick these up and update a database when the process is done.

Comment: The above architecture will allow a web server to handle several orders of magnitude more simultaneous processes than it would be capable of if it was trying to do processing on-thread.  It also allows you to scale out horizontally instead of vertically by adding more execution workers on the back-end of the queue.

Comment: Well, the thing that didn't make sense to me is how is repetitive sending new request in a loop going to help not to exhaust thread pool. It is counter intuitive at first... but when if you put in picture that almost all them are extremely short-lived then it makes sense. However, I don't think in my scenario that I will have a lot of those long runners, so kinda still waging.... Anyway thank you kindly for your explanations.